# Plugin to mark JIRA issue as resolved when pull request is merged

Tags: bitbucket, jira, jira-plugin, bitbucket-server

Is there any Stash/Bitbucket plugin which takes care of marking JIRA issue as resolved when request is merged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Smart Commits for Bitbucket](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.lb.software.stash.smart.commit.lb-software-stash-smart-commit/server/overview) should be able to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is built into JIRA Software as part of the integration with Bitbucket. All that should be required is for you to do some configuration of your JIRA workflow and for you to include Issue keys in your branch names & commit messages.

There is a knowledge base article [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/configuring-workflow-triggers-802592811.html) that documents how to set up workflow triggers.

Comment: Thanks for the reference link.